# Resolution from Size and pixels of an image

Tags: image, compression, resolution, pixel, ppi

Is there any formula to calculate image resolution, if provided with image size and image height and width. I googled for an answer, but didnt get much of a help. Got one formula, but if i calculate with height and width of an image, the resolution i got is different from actual resolution.

Also if i have take a pic from 42 mega Pixel camera and 32 mega pixel camera, will the image size and dimensions vary?

Thanks Jithen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple cross-multiplication

if your image is supposed to have a width of 10 inches and is 1000 pixels wide, its horizontal resolution is 1000 / 10 = 100 ppi (pixels per inch).

Do I missed something ?

Comment: My Image has got 768 X 1028 pixels width and height. So according to u, the resolution should be 768/12.8 = 60 PPI. (12.8 is width size in inches). Am i correct?

Comment: That's correct. Note that horizontal and vertical resolutions can be different.

Comment: Thank you. I have my image size in KB. How to get size in Inches like width inch and height inch.

Comment: There is no relation between the size of a file (in KB) and the dimensions of the image it contains.